# How to configure correctly iptables for run Maples with a blocked internet connection?

Tags: iptables

I would like to be able to run Maple with a blocked internet connection.
For doing so I set my iptables by doing something like this for user joe:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner joe -j REJECT
```

Now I want that joe will be able to use Maple.
The problem is that mserver will not be able to work correctly with the previous iptables configuration.

As it is said on the website of Maple:

> This executable starts automatically in the background when Maple starts.  It communicates with the user interface over a TCP/IP socket.  The socket connection is secure; it is local to the machine running Maple and cannot be accessed from other machines on the network.

How to configure correctly iptables for suppress any communication to the outside network but to be able to run Maple?

Comment: Finally you need to drop every OUTPUT

Comment: @InfectedRoot sorry I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must allow local connections first:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner joe -j REJECT
```